# Svnkit with Subclipse under Eclipse Indigo

Tags: subclipse, svnkit, eclipse-indigo

In my Eclipse Indigo (64-bit) under Ubuntu, the SVNKit client doesn't show up in Eclipse preferences -> Team -> SVN.

I've installed subclipse from Eclipse marketplace.

Since after installing subclipse, the SVNKit wasn't available, I installed svnkit from update site: http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.3.x/

Still, svnkit isn't visible as a SVN client. Only JavaHL is in the combo box.

How to get SVNKit working in Indigo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the SVNKit Client Adapter plugin, from the subclipse update site, in addition to installing the SVNKit plugin.

Comment: Has the SVNKit Adapter plugin been removed from subclipse 1.8? I don't see it in the installation options any more.

Comment: As explained at http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=2862527 1.8 does not support SVNKit.

Answer (score 2):

Installing subversive and uninstalling subclipse will fix all your: `Eclipse preferences -> Team -> SVN`. problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had good luck when I installed from subclipse 1.4

Just add the following to your list of update sites to visit

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.4.x